# Javascript Validation Form Issue

Tags: javascript, forms

I am creating a simple validation form using javascript but there is an issue with my code. I have a username and a password input fields. What i would like is when i submit the form, if one of the fields is empty to not proceed the form to a database but to stay on the page and reveal the span next to the input that says "please fill in this field". How can i fix the issue?

Thanks.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <span id="userspan">please fill in this field</span>

    <br>

    <label for="userpassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="userpassword" name="userpassword">

    <br>

    <input type="submit" id="usersubmit" onsubmit="myFunction();">
</form>
```

CSS Code:

```
#userspan {
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var userpassword = document.getElementById("userpassword").value;
var userspan = document.getElementById("userspan");
var var usersubmit = document.getElementById("usersubmit");


function myFunction() {
    if ( username == "" || userpassword == "" ) {
        userspan.style.display="block";
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the submit input box to:

```
    <input type="button" id="usersubmit" onclick="myFunction();">
```

and add to end of your `myFunction()`  declaration before  the `return true`  declaration.

```
    document.getElemenById("username").form.submit();
```

... The reason is because  the `submit` input button will submit the form no matter what, where as if you use the `button` input type,  it does not submit the form, and you can then control when the form is submitted from within `myFunction()`

You also have in the code:

`var var usersubmit = document.getElementById("usersubmit");`

which says `var var usersubmit`

Example of Javascript:

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var userpassword = document.getElementById("userpassword").value;
    if ((username == "") || (userpassword == "")) {
      userspan.style.display = "block";
      return false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("username").form.submit();
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  <span id="userspan">please fill in this field</span>

  <br>

  <label for="userpassword">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="userpassword" name="userpassword">

  <br>

  <input type="button" id="usersubmit" onclick="myFunction();" value="submit">
</form>
```

Another way without using any javascript:

```html
  <form action="#" method="post">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
      <span id="userspan">please fill in this field</span>

      <br>

      <label for="userpassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="userpassword" name="userpassword" required>

      <br>

      <input type="submit" id="usersubmit" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but the code is not working properly. I have tried what u said and when the fields are filled it does not proceed. It will show me the span message.

Comment: I think you should not do this using basic javascript. If you want to do the same using jquery it will be lot easier. Let me know if you want this using jquery. I will give you the code

Comment: @SPViradiya Thanks but i would like to do it with vanilla javascript.

Comment: got it working in my last edit... if thats what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @ Mike Nickaloff still when the fields are filled the form wont proceed as it should, but when the fields are empty the span message is working properly.

Comment: Have you considered using the `required` attribute on the two `input` elements?

`<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>`

Comment: yes ofc but i would prefer to have my custom message

Comment: Wrap every field in the div. For example wrap username input and span in one div and use this code to show respective error document.getElementById('username-wrap').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.display="block !important";;

Comment: Still not working properly. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Are you using a jsfiddle or something to test this? because you cant submit forms from those

Comment: You had to define the the `username` var and the `userpassword` vars inside of `myFunction()` otherwise they would cause a Javascript error before they finished parsing

Comment: I got it working perfectly fine..
http://www.konkerror.com/snippets/40189398.html

Comment: Yea that seems to work can u provide me ur code please? so i can rate it.

Comment: Its in the answer above (first one) now

Answer (score 0):

Replace onsubmit event with return like this

Change

```
<input type="submit" id="usersubmit" onsubmit="myFunction();">
```

to

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return myFunction();" method="post">
```

```js
function myFunction() {
 var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
 var userpassword = document.getElementById("userpassword").value;
 var useralert = document.getElementById("username_required");
 var passalert = document.getElementById("password_required");

  if (username=="" && userpassword=="") {
   useralert.style.display="block";
   passalert.style.display="block";
    return false;
  }
  else if (username!='' && userpassword=="") {
   useralert.style.display="none";
   passalert.style.display="block";
    return false;
  }
  else if (username=='' && userpassword!="") {
   useralert.style.display="block";
   passalert.style.display="none";
    return false;
  }
  else {
   useralert.style.display="none";
   passalert.style.display="none";
   alert('Your records has been submit!');
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
.alert {
     display:none;
     color: red;
  }
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return myFunction();" method="post">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
   <td valign="top"><label for="username">Username :</label></td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <span class="alert" id="username_required">Please fill in this field</span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top"><label for="userpassword">Password :</label></td>
   <td>
    <input type="password" id="userpassword" name="userpassword">
      <span class="alert" id="password_required">Please fill in this field</span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input type="submit" id="usersubmit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```